Softmax gradient for automatic differentiation
imaging input vector a = {a1,a2,a3}
and z = softmax(a) = {z1,z2,z3}
So, we expect than gradient of z with respect of a would be the same shape as vector a (so we can make gradient step: a = a - learning rate * dz/da). But the real shape is (3,3). So what should i do to make the gradient step? 

(ignoring the fact that is probably the other way around, meaning $z$ are the logits, $a = softmax(z)$)
Automatic differentiation expects you to take the derivative of a function $f: R^N \rightarrow R$, where $f$ for example can be the loss function.
If you have multiple outputs, you cannot apply GD, except if you "collapse/aggregate" these multiple outputs (for example, taking the mean)
From an intuitive perspective, that matrix is telling you "how to change $z$ so that $a$ increases"... you have to decide which of these "$a$" should increase, or, taking the mean of them, averaging over the gradients
